# Button's text is changed using javascript but when clicked, the button's text as received server-side is still unchanged

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a textbox and a button (that says "Activate"). Once the value of the textbox is changed, the text on the button changes to "Search". In the code-behind, it checks whether the button's text says Search or Activate and has different course of actions to be executed for each. But when I click the button while it says "Search" on it, the action it still executes is for when it says "Activate".

This is the function I used which gets called by the textbox's OnKeyDown and OnPaste events:

```
function changeButtonText(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("btnactivate");
    if (elem.value=="Activate")
    elem.value = "Search";}
```

I want to know why this happens. Clearly the button displays "Search" already. I don't get why the code-behind doesn't seem to recognize the change in the button's text. Btw, when I click the button again, it executes the action for "Search" then. I'm confused. Help!

Comment: if you are using hidden field concept then add else condition to update the hidden field value.

Comment: @amitagrawal I'm just trying to understand why this happens. I need an explanation as to why and not how to work around it. Will you explain to me? Thanks ;)

Comment: It is maintaining in Viewstate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any http post back information only related to input types , label information are never posted. If you want to get them on the server side use the hidden fields In you javascript update the value of hidden field part of your FORM tag and then check its value on the server side and do what you want to do

Comment: Hey when I click the button the second time, it does what it's supposed to do. So somehow the change in the button's label gets on the server side.

Comment: Is that with first clicking you are doing postback ? If yes then ASP.NET this form that is generated after the first click will keep the label new name in the view state which will tell the correct name to codebehind 2nd time when it is posted back to Server

Comment: you should read more here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx . Sometime ASP.NET does so much behind the scene that make us more confuse :)